# How to take input as a string and identify each character as a char, int or a float?

Tags: c++

How to take input as a string and identify each character as a char, int or a float in C++?

e.g.: If I want a user to input a simple `3+2 = statement` then I want the program to decide whether I am adding subtracting or doing any other arithmetic operations and then output the appropriate answer accordingly.

Comment: You could loop through each character in your string and identify where the operation is (in this case +). Once you know the operation position, take each character from the beginning of the string to the operation as the first operand, and each character from the operation to the end of the string as the second operand. You can use `atof` to convert the strings into doubles, then do math on the operands. Use an `if` statement to identify the operation character and do the appropriate operation.

Comment: It's all about tokenizing. Google would be a great help

Comment: You could do this with boost spirit, have a look at the example provided: https://github.com/djowel/spirit_x3/blob/master/example/x3/calc5.cpp

Comment: I want a simple running code

Comment: your code on github is not working

Comment: Have you already considered flex and bison?

Comment: This is not a code finding service.

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize your input string with [`std::string.substr(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) or [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match).
Once you've tokenized it, you should make sure the syntax is correct.
Then just execute the syntax.

Here's how you can define your language:

- Seperator = ' '
- Operator = '+', '-', '*', '/'
- Integer = \d+
- Float = \d*.\d+